# Git hangs at fetch but runs fine with pull

Tags: windows-8, git

I am running Windows 8 and Git Bash 2.12.2.

I'm trying to run `git fetch` (or `git fetch origin`) and it hangs at “Unpacking objects: 81%” (after getting stuck at 50% for a bit).

What is weird is that `git pull origin feature/branch` works fine. The repo seems okay because other coworkers can run fetch on their system without a hitch. I tried running `git gc` to no avail.

What could be the issue? I'd like not having to reclone the repo.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue was that someone had pushed a huge file to the repository. That's why `git pull origin feature/branch` worked fine, but doing a `git fetch origin` hung for a long time. He was advised not to do it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Had similar issues after I installed git and used `cmd.exe` to run git commands. The download was simply too large and the command window would freeze up. I could never resolve the issues with `cmd.exe`, so I installed [MINGW64](https://www.mingw-w64.org) instead as a terminal window and ran all my git commands from there.

[Git for Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/), if you go through the installer; it should offer to install MINGW64, install it and customize it as you like.

In my case, this resolved the issue since i was able to fetch a 10GB file with no issues. It froze for about a minute but came back whereas cmd.exe never recovered.

The only two solutions i can think of are:

1. Have you coworker not upload such a huge file uncompressed
2. Try a different terminal other than `cmd.exe` which worked for me.